# map multi json to object with angular

Tags: angular, dictionary, rxjs

I have multiple JSON objects and I need to map them to one object.
The different JSON objects that i have contain unmatching "keys"

Can you please help me find a solution to this problem?

example JSON 1 :

```
[
  {
    "id": 1696,
    "date": "2019-06-27T14:18:11",
    "img": {
      "url": "test"
    },
    {
    "id": 1896,
    "date": "2019-06-27T14:18:11",
    "img": {
      "url": "test1"
    }
]
```

example JSON 2 :

```
[
  {
    "uid": 1696,
    "date": "2019-06-27T14:18:11",
    "img": {
      "link": "test"
    },
    {
    "uid": 1896,
    "date": "2019-06-27T14:18:11",
    "img": {
      "link": "test1"
    }
]
```

Comment: You mean you want to "rename" the `id` property to `uid`?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please make sure to add a minimal verifiable code snippet for others to take a look and understand your problem. For more details on how to create [mcve]

Comment: Tsvetan Ganev - no... I mean if my Key is 'id' or 'uid' I put in some object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an object with all mappings. And use [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to transform each array item.

`mapKeys()` is a recursive function which maps the keys of an object if there exists a mapping for the key.

This works for objects of any nested levels.

```js
let data = [{ "id": 1696, "date": "2019-06-27T14:18:11", "img": { "url": "test" } }, { "id": 1896, "date": "2019-06-27T14:18:11", "img": { "url": "test1" } } ]; 

let map = { "id": "uid", "url": "link" }; 

function mapKeys(obj) {
  Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    if (map[key]) {
      obj[map[key]] = (typeof value === "object") ? mapKeys(value) : value;
      delete obj[key];
    } else {
      obj[key] = (typeof value === "object") ? mapKeys(value) : value;
    }
  });

  return obj;
}

let result = data.map(item => mapKeys(item));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: tnx, Nikhil ... but map() doesn't work on typescript
do you have more ideas?

Comment: @user3148221 - `map()` works in typescript. What is the error you are getting? You can also use a `for` loop to iterate on data array and push mapped elements to a new result array.